# To whom the follow up email must be sent?

Tags: mathematics, job, interview

I interviewed for a Math faculty position including with four persons. I want to know about follow up email. Should I send the follow up email for each an every body in the interview board?

Comment: What "follow up email" are you asking about? A reply to something from them, or just a thank you? Something else?

Comment: @Buffy I sent a thank you email in the day of interview. Now it is almost one week after interview and I want to send a follow up email to ask them about any result.

Comment: @user40491 Unless you were the very last person, there is a 0% chance they've made a decision in less than a week. If you were the last person, it increases to <1%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in many hiring committees in math. If it was the last of several interviews for the position, the decision was likely made during the same day. If so there is no need in any follow up letter. If it was not the last interview, then it is too early for any follow up letter. In any case if the decision is positive you will hear from the hiring committee soon after it is made.